# Ultranav of Thinkpad E540 not working

Tags: lenovo, trackpoint

I have a new Thiknpad E540 which has the 3 additional buttons for the mouse integrated in the touchpad [here](http://www.lenovo.com/images/gallery/1060x596/lenovo-laptop-thinkpad-e540-touch-touchpad-detail-9.jpg). My previous thinkpad had 3 separate buttons like those [here](http://www.lenovo.com/images/OneWebImages/SubSeries/gallery/laptops/ThinkPad-T530-Laptop-PC-Overhead-Keyboard-View-gallery-940x529.jpg)
which worked perfectly. 
The touchpad itself is working fine just the buttons ain't. In Windows they work, even the middle one for scrolling!!
I've installed the package 'configure-trackpoint' but that didn't help...

Here's the input devices

```
dmesg | grep input
[    0.559561] input: Lid Switch as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
[    0.560750] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1
[    1.133358] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
[   11.984388] input: ThinkPad Extra Buttons as /devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input3
[   12.057888] psmouse serio1: synaptics: serio: Synaptics pass-through port at isa0060/serio1/input0
[   12.103377] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
[   12.965768] input: Integrated Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-12/3-12:1.0/input/input5
[   13.981071] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input6
[   14.049867] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input7
[   14.049920] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input8
[   14.049956] input: HDA Intel MID HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input9
[   14.079953] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input10
[   14.079996] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input11
[   19.190549] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input12
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a script I found here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/1246683, works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get install libevdev-dev libevdev2
sudo apt-get build-dep xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.9.0.orig.tar.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.9.0-1ubuntu1.diff.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.9.0-1ubuntu1.dsc

wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.8.0.orig.tar.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.8.0-1~exp2ubuntu2.diff.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.8.0-1~exp2ubuntu2.dsc

dpkg-source -x --no-check xserver-xorg-input-evdev_2.9.0-1ubuntu1.dsc
dpkg-source -x --no-check xserver-xorg-input-synaptics_1.8.0-1~exp2ubuntu2.dsc

wget https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xf/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint/xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint.tar.gz

tar -xzf xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint.tar.gz

mv xf86-input-evdev-trackpoint arch
mv xserver-xorg-input-evdev-2.9.0 evdev
mv xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-1.8.0 synaptics

cp synaptics/src/{eventcomm.c,eventcomm.h,properties.c,synaptics.c,synapticsstr.h,synproto.c,synproto.h} evdev/src
cp synaptics/include/synaptics-properties.h evdev/src
cp arch/*.patch evdev

cd evdev
patch -p1 -i 0001-implement-trackpoint-wheel-emulation.patch
patch -p1 -i 0004-disable-clickpad_guess_clickfingers.patch
patch -p1 -i 0006-add-synatics-files-into-Makefile.am.patch

dpkg-buildpackage

cd ..
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-input-evdev_*.deb
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo cp arch/90-evdev-trackpoint.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d

echo If everything was OK, than logout/reboot and enjoy fully working ThinkPad Trackpoint/ClickPad
echo If you want to deactivate touch area of ClickPad for pure TrackPoint usage
echo edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-evdev-trackpoint.conf and change "0" to "1" at line
echo Option "AreaBottomEdge" "0"
```